# Laravel Check if can connect to DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'am trying to prevent `query` to DB if connection is not possible.
Basically if can't connect and `app_debug = false` it jusst throws 500 error and if `app_debug = true` shows error trace.

I need when ther is no connection to DB just return an empty `array`
Until now I tried this:

```
foreach(config('some_config') as $v){
    if(config('database.connections.'.$v)){{
       if(DB::connection($v)->getDatabaseName()){
          //ther is connection can query DB
       }
      //no connection next element
    }
}
```

But still I get a 500 error, any suggestions? (laravel way, whithout using `PDO or mysqli_connect`

Comment: Have you tried `if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
{}` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I need to test it on specific connection, not on default one

Comment: Use a `try catch` to catch the exception that is thrown then run your `if` statement

Comment: @HelderLucas sorry didnt include in My question I'm checking connection in loop (2-3) items max, and creating an array if connection is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using try catch as was recommended by @Helder Lucas